# send emails for 34 weeks from registration date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

new on ruby and using windows xp and rails 3, i want to send emails to the users every 7 days for 34 weeks, i have usermailer that send emails every 7 days i want also **for 34 weeks**??

i have user mailer send emails to user, and i have defined a method to send emails every 7 days
and call it from a batch file using also a windows task scheduler
also i want to know which week is the user now in??

e.g user gets pregnant on April and singed up in June, then there will be a welcome message,then the first 8 weeks of her pregnancy wasn`t in our records that means the emails will start from week number 9 because 34 - 8 = 26 weeks so the user will receive 26 emails (1 email every 1 week).

my model:

```
class Dop < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :date, :mail, :name
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_presence_of :mail
  validates_uniqueness_of :mail
  validates_format_of :mail, :with =>
  %r{^(?:[_a-z0-9-]+)(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@([a-z0-9-]+)(\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.] 
  +)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$}i

  def self.send_mail
    Dop.all.each do |dop|
      UserMailer.welcome_email(dop).deliver if dop.date.to_time <= Time.now - 7.day
    end
  end
end
```

my batch file :

```
 echo rails run
 cd c:\dop
 rails r "Dop.send_mail"

 echo done
 pause
```

Dop is refer to date of pregnancy.

Comment: i want to send emails every 7 days for 34 weeks

Comment: the problem is how to keep it for 34 weeks??

Comment: better switch to linux/Mac and use cron. Believe me you'll have problem using windows sytem for rails development.

Comment: not exactly am using task scheduler in windows, my problem is how to keep sending for 34 weeks from user date??
am sending mails easily every 7 days but to make it for 34 weeks is the problem.

Comment: Tell us more about your environment, your developing on windows xp and we can assume your using sqlite.  What will your production machine be running on and the database.  I feel like you'll have a better experience using a database query to restrict the results. `Dob.all` will perform poorly on an active site.

Comment: yes am using sqlite for now, am trying to learn ruby and am working on my own trial site i want to understand all ruby by doing some exercises

Comment: I think there will not be much of a response to this since most of the developers use either linux or apple OS to develop in RoR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your environment, a pure ruby solution would look like this:

```
class Dop < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.send_mail
    Dop.all.each do |dop|
      UserMailer.welcome_email(dop).deliver if within_thirty_four_weeks?(date) && seventh_day(dop.date) 
    end
  end

  def self.seventh_day?(date)
    days_diff % 7 == 0
  end

  def self.within_thirty_four_weeks?(date)
    days_diff(date) <= 34.weeks
  end

  def self.days_diff(date)
    (Time.zone.now - date).to_i / 1.day
  end
end
```

However, I prefer a more database solution.  Wherein this gets more complicated, sqlite does not have the same date functions as MySql or Postgres.  (Sqlite can be patched to keep your test/development environment like production, but I'm saving that for another question.)

```
class Dop < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.send_mail
    Dop.where("(julianday('now') - julianday(date(date))) % 7 = 0").
        where("date('now', '-238 days') < date").
        each do |dop|
          UserMailer.welcome_email(dop).deliver
    end
  end
end
```

Personally, the database solution (option 2), is the most elegant solution. Though it is more fragile, because it is specific to sqlite's date functions.

Schedule this to run nightly and it will email every 7 days for 34 weeks.

Comment: What is julianday?? is it the relative to GMT??

Comment: this way isn`t what i want, because if the user edit his date it won`t change it will still at created date

Comment: maybe i can use some thing like this :

dop.where date.to_time=time.now - 238.day

Comment: UserMailer.welcome_email(dop).deliver where dop.date.to_time = time.now - 238 day && if dop.date.to_time <= Time.now - 7.day

Comment: can i replace created_at with date??

Comment: @Abdulrahman_88 Julianday is a sqlite method to calculate the number of days for the date. Yes, you'll need to replace created_at with date.  I tested this query on my local instance, so I'll edit above.

Comment: thanks it worked but i want it to be dynamic, like emails will be sent based on which week is the user now

Comment: You'll need to calculate the week the user is in and send the email you want them to get.  Something like:  ((Time.zone.now - date).to_i / 1.week).to_i

Answer (score 0):

i`ve solved it by adding 1 line of code to my class method

```
 def self.send_mail
  Dop.all.each do |dop| 
  where(dop.date.to_time <= Time.now - 34.week)
  UserMailer.welcome_email(dop).deliver if dop.date.to_time <= Time.now - 7.day
   end
 end
```

Comment: If you want send 34 emails, once a week, then "dop.date.to_time <= Time.now - 7.day" will not work.  As I read it, this will send an email on the first week, but the second week will not meet that condition.

Comment: i`ve call it with batch file then put the batch file into task scheduler, like cron scheduler